# Python: Unable to easy_install (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: python, windows, distutils, windows-7-x64, pysqlite

I'm running python 2.7 on Windows 7 x64, and trying to easy_install pysqlite.

With command: `easy_install -U pysqlite`

It exits with the error:

> error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

This site: http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/issues/detail?id=104#c4
suggests a workaround of installing MingGW, saying to check the g++ option on install (plus some other stuff).

Unfortunately, MingGW does not give me the option to install g++, only c++, and of course on running easy_install a second time, I get ".. command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory". So now I am el stucko.

Any advice on how to fix this problem would be great!

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 2.6 comes with sqlite3 module included by default and you don't need to install any other modules to use sqlite3

Comment: Hah! thanks. This actually helped - I was trying to execute: import sqlite2. but import sqlite3 works. Now if only I can get serial comms to work on x64!

Comment: Did you install a 64-bit version of Python 2.7 or a 32 bit version? There are a lot of issues with installing addon packages with the 64 bit version. I've had too many problems with that. If you installed the 64 bit version I recommend switching to 32 bit version.

Comment: I am using the 64 bit one, and it has been a major headache. I'll try the 32 bit one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you install a compiler (MinGW or Visual Studio), you still have to install SQLite3 development libraries. It is a pain to build things on Windows, so I suggest that you get the **[unofficial pre-built Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysqlite)** and install it.

*As an aside, you should probably consider [switching to ActivePython](http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads) as it includes a package manager that allows you to install pre-built modules from [ActiveState's repository](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/).*

As for the particular error in question, that is a distutils bug and you should raise your concerns in [the Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue2698).

Answer (score 0):

When that says "g++ compiler" they really mean the C++ compiler, which for mingw is gcc.

Comment: Understood. But how to I get it to find that?

Comment: You probably have to put it in your computer's Path environment variable. Go to Control Panel>System>Advanced System Settings. You should have C:\MinGW\bin in the Path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft Visual C compiler thingy (the 2010 one). And use that as your compiler for all modules. You can also mess with distuls.cfg and specify a compiler that way.

Comment: Can you give me some more details? I have a the Visual Studio 2010 professional installed, if that helps.

Comment: I think thats the one. Put everything there in your path then try again.